# Huggingface Transformers - AttributeError: 'MrpcProcessor' object has no attribute 'tfds_map'

Tags: transformer-model, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

When using Hugginface Transformers on GLUE task, I've got the error `AttributeError: 'MrpcProcessor' object has no attribute 'tfds_map'`

I suspect a problem of compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to simply to downgrade the version of transformers to 2.2.0

`pip uninstall transformers -y`

`pip install transformers==2.2.0`

Comment: I need 2.3.0 as 2.2.0 does not yet provide the pipeline-class which I started using and appreciating. Bow I run into the same error. You don't happen to have another idea rather than downgrading, do you? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using `transformers 2.11.0` and this code works for me:

```
# First we create an empty Byte-Pair Encoding model (i.e. not trained model)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE())
tokenizer.normalizer = Sequence([
    NFKC(),
    Lowercase()
])
```

So there seems to be a constructor which you can use.